# Masstransit state machine transitions

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

So, I must be missing something, it seems to me that my state machine blocks execute even if the event doesn't happen. This is my state machine:

```
public class OrderStateMachine : MassTransitStateMachine<NormalScanState>
{
    public OrderStateMachine()
    {
        Event(() => OrderScannedEvent, x => x.CorrelateById(context => context.Message.CorrelationId));
        Event(() => OrderDataRetrieved,
            x => x.CorrelateById(context => context.Message.CorrelationId));
        Event(() => SortingGeneratedEvent,
            x => x.CorrelateById(context => new Guid(context.GetHeader("correlation-id")!)));

        InstanceState(x => x.CurrentState);

        Initially(
            When(OrderScannedEvent)
                .Then(context =>
                {
                    context.Saga.CorrelationId = context.Message.CorrelationId;
                    context.Saga.OrderId = context.Message.OrderId;
                    context.Saga.OrderData.TrackingNumber = context.Message.TrackingNumber;
                })
                .Activity(x => x.OfType<GetOrderActivity>())
                .TransitionTo(GetOrderSubmitted));

        During(GetOrderSubmitted,
            Ignore(OrderScannedEvent),
            Ignore(SortingGeneratedEvent),
            When(OrderDataRetrieved)
                .Publish(context => new GenerateSorting
                    {
                        Height = context.Saga.OrderData.Height,
                        Length = context.Saga.OrderData.Length,
                    }
                    , AddHeaders)
                .TransitionTo(GenerateSortingSubmitted));

        During(GenerateSortingSubmitted,
            Ignore(OrderScannedEvent),
            Ignore(OrderDataRetrieved),
            When(SortingGeneratedEvent)
                .Then(context =>
                {
                    context.Saga.OrderData.SortCode = context.Message.SortCode;
                    context.Saga.OrderData.RouteCode = context.Message.RouteCode;
                    context.Saga.OrderData.Carrier = context.Message.Carrier;
                })              
                .TransitionTo(Accepted));

    }


    public State GetOrderSubmitted { get; private set; }
    public State GenerateSortingSubmitted { get; private set; }  
    public State Accepted { get; private set; }


    public Event<OrderSubmitted>? OrderSubmittedEvent { get; private set; }
    public Event<OrderDataRetrieved> OrderDataRetrieved { get; private set; }
    public Event<SortingGenerated> SortingGeneratedEvent { get; private set; }

    private void AddHeaders(PublishContext publishContext)
    {
        var consumeContext = publishContext.GetPayload<ConsumeContext>();
        var correlationId = consumeContext.CorrelationId;
        publishContext.Headers.Set("correlation-id", correlationId);
    }
}
```

Even if OrderDataRetrieved and GenerateSortingSubmitted events don't happen the code inside During(GetOrderSubmitted) and During(GenerateSortingSubmitted) gets executed.

This is my installer:

```
public void InstallServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddMassTransit(cfg =>
        {
            var entryAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
            
            cfg.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
            cfg.SetInMemorySagaRepositoryProvider();
   
            cfg.AddConsumers(entryAssembly);
            cfg.AddSagaStateMachines(entryAssembly);
            cfg.AddSagas(entryAssembly);
            cfg.AddActivities(entryAssembly);   
            
            cfg.UsingRabbitMq((context, configurator) =>
            {
                configurator.Host(queueConfig.ConnectionString);
            

                configurator.DeployPublishTopology = true;

                configurator.ClearSerialization();
                configurator.UseRawJsonSerializer(RawSerializerOptions.AnyMessageType);

                configurator.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
            });
        });
    }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`configurator.UseRawJsonSerializer(RawSerializerOptions.AnyMessageType);`

This isn't going to work with a saga that is consuming multiple event types, since it will treat every inbound message as a message that matches every event in the state machine.

The [documentation](https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/serialization#raw-json) covers how raw JSON works.

Comment: Is there a way to set this raw json serializer for only some messages, not all? Specifically, I need that for messages I'm sending to another service

Comment: [Yes](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/a907378730702663fe1fb0d0ecc107e4280781b2/tests/MassTransit.Tests/Topology/MessageSerializer_Specs.cs#L37) you can specify a content type for a specific message type.

Comment: Thank you, Chris, for answering!
And what about receiving a raw message back as a response? Is there a way to set up my saga to receive this message without it breaking the saga and matching all messages to all events?
I thought I could configure only one endpoint but I couldn't figure it out.